# Apply returning differing answer for different sizes, R

Tags: r, apply

I am running into some very confusing behavior from the apply function in base R. Essentially, what my code does is it counts instances of value before and after a date variable

```
beforedates2008 = c('11/02', '11/03', '11/04')
beforedates2010 = c()
beforedates2012 = c('11/02', '11/03', '11/04', '11/05', '11/06')
beforedates2014 = c('11/02', '11/03', '11/04')
beforedates2016 = c('11/02', '11/03', '11/04', '11/05', '11/06', '11/07', '11/08')
befores = list(beforedates2008, beforedates2010, beforedates2012, beforedates2014, beforedates2016)
before_nonv <- function(row_cur){
    return(sum(row_cur[10:14][sapply(befores, function(y) row_cur[18] %in% y)] == 0 | is.na(row_cur[10:14][sapply(befores, function(z) row_cur[18] %in% z)])))
}
be_t = apply(subs_dates, 1, before_nonv)
```

My data is called subs_dates, and to give you a sense of what's going wrong

```
be_t[1:10]
```

Returns

```
22  43  76 317 387 444 520 523 660 734 
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

While the other way goes like this:

```
apply(subs_dates[1:10, ], 1, before_nonv)
```

Returns

```
22  43  76 317 387 444 520 523 660 734 
0   3   0   1   3   0   1   0   0   0
```

The second of the two is correct. Running `apply(subs_dates[1:nrow(subs_dates), ], 1, before_nonv)` gives the same incorrect answer as the general, larger apply, however. 
Google drive link to data included for reproduceability:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15pDdUbQIS1pk4C1pt1e0dx2hu16Dunnm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the function doing? Could you provide a sample example and expected output? Instead debugging, we could provide a better solution.

Comment: The function is supposed take all the election years (columns 10 through 14) and check if the election fell before or on the date listed in the bdaynoyr column (the last column) and count those instances. The dates falling before or on the election that I care about are in the befores list of vectors.

While I would love another quick non-loop answer I would also really like to know ahy apply is doing this

Comment: Sample example

   ` before_nonv(subs_dates[2, ])`

    `[1] 3`


where the input is


   State  voter_ID First_name Middle_name Last_name race  birthdate registration_date gender turnout2008 turnout2010 turnout2012 turnout2014 turnout2016 residence_zipcode
43    FL 114098696  Elizabeth    Kathleen    Radtke    5 11/04/1987        02/23/2006      F           2           0           0           0           0             32605
   mailing_zipcode birthday_pos bdaynoyr
43                   1987-11-04    11/04

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, but the point is that the date 11/04 comes on one of the dates listed in the beforedates object for 2008 (but not 2010 which is empty on purpose) 2012, 2014, and 2016. It has a 0 or NA for 2012, 2014, and 2016 out of those, for a total of 3. The desired result is 3.